# How to enforce SSL on a Node.js app on heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, heroku, https

I'm trying to deploy a Node.js app on Heroku using express, and I am struggling to enforce HTTPS on all incoming traffic. I am using the express-sslify library to do this using the code below, which is identical to the express-sslify docs, but the website still accepts non-HTTPS traffic. Any advice on what to correct and/or alternative middleware to use would be greatly appreciated!

server.js file

```
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
var enforce = require('express-sslify');
var http = require('http');

var express = require('express');
var serveStatic = require("serve-static")
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(history());
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
http.createServer(app).listen(port)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is eg. this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sslify

You just write import and one line of code.

```
const enforce = require('express-sslify');

app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));
```

One important thing, it needs to be put before all custom endpoints, putting this after custom endpoints may block it from working.

Answer (score -1):

Please read this article for Heroku headers
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers

Git URL: https://github.com/cmdr-dhiraj-laddha/heroku_force_ssl

The Below code may help you force SSL

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5003;

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var forceSsl = function (req, res, next) {
 if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
     return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
 }
 return next();
};

 if (env === 'production') {
     app.use(forceSsl);
 }

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World! - '+env)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm following the suggested heroku approach which is to use a library/middleware to do this (https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls) - effectively sslify is very similar to the function you have provided here. However, even writing my own middleware like you suggested does not enforce SSL so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: Made demo code for testing this SSL update at this git repo https://github.com/cmdr-dhiraj-laddha/heroku_force_ssl  also confirmed by deploy at heroku app.